# How can I temporarily disable Oracle connection from local Windows 7 machine to a db server? 

Tags: oracle, windows-7

For testing purposes. One option is to disable network connection but this seems to disable IIS for some reason.

I would like to prevent a web service to have a connection to a db on different machine. Changing anything on server side is not an option.

EDIT: I have to do this on specific point during the Web Service's (and it's consumer's) execution. I'm trying to simulate a situation where the connection to db is suddenly lost while serving a request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TNS based naming for the database, remove the name temporarily from the `tnanames.ora` file.

To do it at the OS level, configure your Windows 7 Firewall (advanced seting). Add an outbound block rule for the IP/port of the DB server.

Comment: thanks Raihan! I edited my question so I'm not sure tnsnames.ora will solve this since i don't think it's reading the file all the time. Gotta check though.